# Need jaxb to xml return xml with full package name

Tags: java, jaxb

I have class file, say "com.main.module.Test.java". I need to convert this file into xml. If I use javax.xml.bind.JAXB, the returning xml looks like:

```
<Test>
 <sample>
 </sample>
</Test>
```

But I need the xml to be displayed like:

```
<com.main.module.Test>
 <com.main.module.sample>
 </com.main.module.sample>
</com.main.module.Test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the elements anything you want, as long as it's a [valid name](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Name).

Example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "com.main.module.Test")
class Foo {
    @XmlElement(name = "com.main.module.sample")
    String bar;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.bar = "Hello World";

        Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class).createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<com.main.module.Test>
    <com.main.module.sample>Hello World</com.main.module.sample>
</com.main.module.Test>
```

As you can see, the root element name has nothing to do with the class name, and the subelement name has nothing to do with the field name.